# Sorting values while maintaining non-logical ordering

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table which is currently sorted according to the Site Number. These Site Numbers are not in any logical order, but I wish to retain the order of the Site Numbers, while sorting by a different field. This is what an example of the data looks like:

[image]

And this is what I want it to look like:

[image]

In the real data set the number of rows per SiteNo changes (i.e. site 50 has 23 rows, size 102 has 88 rows). Is there an easy way to maintain the ordering of SiteNo and sort it by distance? I have thought of manual ways of achieving this, but I'm sure that Pandas has a feature that's able to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
df = df.set_index(['siteNo']).sort_values(['Distance']).reset_index()
```

Update

```
df.update(df.groupby('siteNo').transform(lambda x : x.sort_values()))
```

Comment: Doing this ends up sorting the dataframe by the index value, so the order of the index becomes 1, 2, 5 rather than 1, 5, 2. The siteNo's are not sorted into a logical order, but maintaining their order is important.